# flush System.out with own logger

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging, system.out

I created my own little logger to use instead of System.out.println

```
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
logger = Logger.getLogger(this.toString());
logger.setLevel(loglevel);
Formatter formatter = new Formatter() {
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        return new Date().toString().substring(11, 20) + record.getLevel()+" " + formatMessage(record) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
};
logger.addHandler(new StreamHandler(System.out, formatter));
LogManager.getLogManager().addLogger(logger);
```

At the moment, the messages don't get flushed, so they only appear once the application gets terminated. Is there a way to flush a message after printing it out without creating a new class or adding many lines of code? I want to keep this code as short as possible...

Comment: I am deleting my answer because calling flush on the Handler is not invoking flush on the stream

Comment: What JVM, O/S, and IDE are you using?

Comment: Java 8, Windows 10, Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the [StreamHandler.setOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.html#setOutputStream-java.io.OutputStream-) wraps the given stream in a [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-) which according to the [javadocs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179662):

> The resulting bytes are accumulated in a buffer before being written to the underlying output stream. The size of this buffer may be specified, but by default it is large enough for most purposes.

So there is no way around calling `StreamHandler.flush` to force those bytes to the console.

Since you don't want to create a new class you can use the [ConsoleHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html#ConsoleHandler--) which will flush to console but by default will write to error stream.  You can get around that if you haven't started any other threads by doing the following:

```
//Global resource so ensure single thread.
final PrintStream err = System.err;
System.setErr(System.out);
try {
    ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
    ch.setFormatter(formatter);
    logger.addHandler(ch);
} finally {
    System.setErr(err);
}
```

A subclass really is your best bet because you can end up accidentally closing the `System.out` by calling `Handler.close()` through `LogManager.getLogManager().reset()` or by calling `StreamHandler.setOutputStream` which means you won't see any output at all.

```
public class OutConsoleHandler extends StreamHandler {
    public OutConsoleHandler(OutputStream out, Formatter f) {
        super(out, f);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {
        super.publish(record);
        flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
        flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI. This does not flush to console either (PrintStream)

Comment: jep the first does not work. Looks like I have to unfortunately use the subclass -.-